# just a quicky on currency in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have `<label>{{cart.on_sale_price|currency:"$"}}</label>` this gives $

now I have cart.currency="INR" in my json response ;

is it possible to write the dynamic currency like

```
cart.on_sale_price|currency:{{cart.currency}}
```

I tried it but doesn't work, is there any method to implement the same ,
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave `{{}}` out:

```
cart.on_sale_price|currency:cart.currency
```

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/VX5YYUIRpyGZzCiyiQJx?p=preview)</kbd>

`{{cart.on_sale_price|currency}}`is already an angular expression, so you can't have `{{}}` inside of `{{}}`.